# How do I find out how many bundles of '1' are there in a String in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to know how many bundles of '1' are there in a String which will only consist of `1`s and `0`s.

> For example,
>
> For `1011011`, the number bundles of '1' will be `3` since bundles are `1`, `11`, `11` excepting `0`s.
>
> For `11101110101`, it will be `4` as well since the bundles are `111`, `111`, `1`, `1`.

Is there any Pythonic and concise way of solving this problem?

Comment: in last example would't it be 4?

Comment: @PriteshThaker Thank you for the correction :) I have edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy.

```
import re
string = "11101110101"
bundles = re.findall(r'1+',string)
```

Use a greedy search to search the longest sequence of `1's`. Now, `re.findall`, greedily searches the whole string, and return a list. This list will contain all the occurrences of 1, which contains groups of 1's.
If you want to print total number of bundles, use this:

`print(len(bundles))`
Output:
`4`

Answer (score 1):

here is how you do it.
split the string by 0 and then remove empty elements from returned list and then print the length of list

```
string = '0000'
x = string.split('0')
while "" in x:
    x.remove('')
print(len(x))
```

another approach would be using loop comprehension to remove empty.

```
string = '0000'
x = string.split('0')
x = [y for y in x if y != ""]
print(len(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and use `'0'` as the splitting character:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> s = '11101110101'
>>> sum(1 for k, g in groupby(s, '0'.__eq__) if not k)
4
```

It's not particularly pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**String which will only consist of 1s and 0s**

```
s = raw_input("Enter: ")
print(len([i for i in s.split("0") if i!=""]))
```

Comment: What if the string has repeated zeroes? E.g. `10110011`

Comment: Now, check my submitted code again and tell me ,if you find any fail test case.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way (to type) is this:

```
s = "11101110101"
print( zip("0"+s,s).count( ('0','1') ) )
```

Explaining why it works is a little more complicated, but good practice for programming in general. Each of the bundles of 1s starts with the substring "01" except for the case where the string starts with a one. If you only count these pairs of adjacent characters then you count the bundles exactly.

Zipping a string with the-string-offset-by-one will give all of the pairs of characters, e.g.

```
>>> s="111001101011"
>>> print( zip(s,s[1:]) )
[('1', '1'), ('1', '1'), ('1', '0'), ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '1'), ('1', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '1')]
```

All that is left to do is fix the corner case where it may start with a '1' by adding an extra '0' to the beginning.

Enjoy.